# write a basic formula in VBA code for Excel (string date text to date format)

Tags: excel, vba

Our accounting software exports dates as 07262013 as text.  To convert this string of text to date format, I normally type the formula

```
=IF(A2>10000000,DATE(VALUE(RIGHT(A2,4)),VALUE(LEFT(A2,2)),VALUE(MID(A2,3,2))),
DATE(VALUE(RIGHT(A2,4)),VALUE(LEFT(A2,1)),VALUE(MID(A2,2,2))))
```

each time I export data.  I want to write a custom function as `=convert_text(text)` to complete the same function.

I came up with

```
Function Convert_Date(text)
 If text > 10000000 Then
    Convert_Date = Application.Date(Application.Value(Application.Right(text, 4)), Application.Value(Application.Left(text, 2)), Application.Value(Application.Mid(text, 3, 2)))
 Else
    Convert_Date = Application.Date(Application.Value(Application.Right(text, 4)), Application.Value(Application.Left(text, 1)), Application.Value(Application.Mid(text, 2, 2)))
End Function
```

Thank you so much in advance!
Lee

Comment: I can see some issues, but without assuming they are typos, what is the problem you're seeing?

Comment: a simpler formula version might be `=TEXT(MID(A2&A2,5,8),"0000-00-00")+0`

Comment: what is the question? Yours is fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the following:

```
Function Convert_Date(text)
' assuming text is of the form mmddyyyy
' or mddyyyy
Dim year As Integer, month As Integer, day As Integer, L As Integer

L = Len(text)
year = Val(Right(text, 4))
day= Val(Mid(text, L - 5, 2))
If L = 7 Then month= Left(text, 1) Else month= Left(text, 2)

' >>>>> the next line is there for debugging; 
' >>>>> take it out once you are happy with the result
MsgBox "year: " & year & "; month: " & month & "; day: " & day

Convert_Date = DateSerial(year, month, day)

End Function
```

This returns the "date serial number". You then format the cell with the date format you want, and you're good to go. Note that using explicit extraction of year, month, day makes the code much more readable.

Note - if you wanted to be more general, you could specify the format as an optional second string; e.g. `ddmmyyyy` in which case you could search for these characters and use that to extract the date properly:

```
Function Convert_Date(text, Optional formatString)
' assuming text is of the form mmddyyyy
' alternatively specify the format with the second parameter

Dim L As Integer, ii As Integer
Dim yearString As String, monthString As String, dayString As String

If IsMissing(formatString) Then formatString = "ddmmyyyy"

L = Len(text)

For ii = 1 To L
  c = Mid(formatString, ii, 1)
  t = Mid(text, ii, 1)
  If c = "d" Then dayString = dayString & t
  If c = "m" Then monthString = monthString & t
  If c = "y" Then yearString = yearString & t
Next ii

Convert_Date = DateSerial(Val(yearString), Val(monthString), Val(dayString))

End Function
```

Comment: I switched the month and day code, they appeared backwards and removed the msgbox as it was gave me almost two hundred msgboxs when I copied the custom function down.  THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: Happy you were able to make it work for you. The msgbox was there for debugging... it was always intended you would take it out once you got the results you wanted. I will fix the code - you're right that was a bug. No need to leave the "wrong" answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))
```

no need! its already there :) if you need to do this in a fx it could look like this

```
function convert_date(text As String) As Date
   convert_date = EVALUATE("DATE(YEAR(text),MONTH(text),DAY(text))")
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

quickest i can think of is

```
Public Function FUNNYDATE(text As String) As Date
    Dim padded As String
    padded = Format(text, "00000000")
    FUNNYDATE = DateSerial(Right(padded, 4), Left(padded, 2), Mid(padded, 3, 2))
End Function
```

Also, not that you do but in case it comes up in certain suggested solutions, I would steer clear of using DATEVALUE("mm-dd-yyyy") as its result depends on the locale of the user. Always stick to DATESERIAL(year,month,day)